# Why is rails adding the CSS class of a button as an URL parameter?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style links with Rails' `link_to` helper and Bootstrap CSS styles.

Here's one of my links:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', controller: 'welcome', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

The style gets applied to the link, however the url that `link_to` generates has the css class as a parameter in it, suggesting I'm doing something wrong, like this:

`/welcome/index?class=btn+btn-primary`

Why is this happening and is there a better way to apply css styles to links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Home", controller: "welcome", action: "your_action", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "Home", welcome_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: The first one still adds the url parameter. 
`<%= link_to "Home", welcome_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>` works (with `welcome_index_path` instead of `welcome_path`)

Answer (score 0):

The class should be in [html_options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) encapsulated between curly braces:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

Try

```
<%= link_to 'Home', controller: 'welcome', {:class => "btn btn-primary"} %>
```

Comment: I get `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...{:class => "btn btn-primary"} );` with that.